# printing the html response back on the html page

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs and springmvc in the application. My requirement is to hit the webpage(URL) and whatever response it returns(basically it returns html content of the webpage accessed through URL) i need to show on the html page.
Below is my code:

**one.html**

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    <table style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td ng-controller="getHTMLController">
                <h1>HIT the URL and get the response</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {{htmlResponsedata}}
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
myApp
    .controller("getHtmlDataController", [
        "$scope", 'MyService',
        function ($scope, MyService) {

            MyService.fetch().then(function (response) {
                $scope.htmlResponsedata = response;
            }, function (errResponse) {
                $scope.cancelModal();
                $rootScope.showError(500, "Internal error");
            });

            _myServiceFactory.fetch = function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var repUrl = myAppURL + '/percentValues/' + '/getHtmlData.form';
                $http.get(repUrl).then(function (response) {
                        console.log("response");
                        derred.resolve(response.data);
                    },
                    function (errResponse) {
                        console.error('Error while fetching data');
                        deferred.reject(errResponse);
                    }
                );
                return deferred.promise;
            }

        }

    ]);
```

**Java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getHtmlData", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public  @ResponseBody String getHtmlData() throws Exception {

      URL url = new URL("https://xyz/abc.com/values/reports");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = ((HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection());
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0");
        InputStream input;
        input = connection.getInputStream();
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String msg;
        while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println("--------------------"+msg);
       return msg; //html code of the URL
    }
}
```

Above is my entire code written using angularjs and springMVC. How to print the data returned by msg from java code on the oe.html page.I have used {{htmlResponsedata}} but the response is not printed. htmlResponsedata is the response i got and which i have set `$scope.htmlResponsedata  = response` in the js code as shown above. Any suggestions as how to print the html response back on the screen?

Comment: Is the ``$scope.htmlResponsedata = response;`` code being hit after the request? and what is the  ``_myServiceFactory.fetch = function () { ... }`` doing there? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: It has <!Doctype ....><html>...</html>, basically it reads the content of the URL being hit.As shown in the java code, i'm returning it as a String object. _myServiceFactory.fetch is a service call to the java code, I just kept js code together for understanding purpose. All the calls are happening and as i said it is returning an html content in the string format. Now i want to display that in the html code.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors are displayed.. I think I need to forward the response back to the HTML page in different approach, as I can alert the response in MyService.fetch() where I had assigned the response to scope.htmlResponseData which I had printed in HTML using {{htmlResponseData}}.

Comment: Well first of all you should change the ``{{htmlResponsedata}}`` to something like this ``<div ng-bind-html="htmlResponsedata"></div>``. You will also have to include ``ng-sanitize`` module to do this. It is also possible the view will not update correctly because the ``htmlResponsedata`` is a string, it is not wrapped inside an object and you are not using ``controllerAs``.